# beautifulsoup tag element contents() strip() method throw TypeError: Nonetype is not callable

Tags: beautifulsoup, nonetype

case 1st:

```
<li class="chapters">
<i>In</i> 
<i>vitro</i> 
blahblah1 
<i>in</i> 
<i>vitro</i> 
blahblah2 
<a href="***">View details</a>
</li>
```

case 2nd:

```
<li class="chapters">   
blahblah2 
<a href="***">View details</a>
</li>
```

I got 2 problems:
Problem 1st: when I use .contents[0].strip(), to get the blahblahs, case 2nd works. but will throw TypeError: Nonetype is not callable.
At case 1st. .contents[0] of case 1st is a tag: *In*. is this a Nonetype? it's a tag but no Nonetype.
Problem 2nd: how can I use one or two lines to deal with these 2 cases. the reason why case 1st exists I guess is the input error of the website.

by the way, I use the Beautifulsoup & lxml to parse the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select `a` tag then get previous content using `.previous_sibling`

```
texts = soup.select('.chapters a')

for t in texts:
    print(t.previous_sibling.strip())
```

Comment: thank you. This can solve the problem of problem2. can you help to analyze the Nonetype problem.

Comment: contents[0] is this: '<i>In</i>', is a tag, is not empty or Nonetype. @unigtea   here i've print the type length content as 'get_titles <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 1 <i>In</i>'

Comment: please update your question, how you select the tag and if you can post the URL

Comment: <li class="chapters"><i>In</i> <i>vitro</i> blahblah <i>in</i> <i>vitro</i> blahblah2 <a href="***">View details</a></li>

Comment: above is the very exact outer html copied. including spaces.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, update and share your code here https://onlinegdb.com/nVUMLsud5

Comment: @unigtea, sorry, for some reason, I can not tell the url.  But I am thinking if .strip() method can only word on string, right, if it was put onto a tag, it will throw that TypeError, mistaken the non-string type as None? is this hypothesis right?

Comment: I am doing the test, I'll let you know soon.

Comment: yes strip() is for string type only. check if it None before strip()

Comment: @unigtea, yes, it's not None, is a tag, bs4.element tag, it can be print, but if you use .strip() behind, because .strip() work only on string, maybe it takes all non-string type as None. so there can be a conclusion: we can not follow these Error message just literally , it's misguiding me whole day long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229008/discussion-between-sampan0423-and-uingtea).